# Internationalization in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, internationalization

What's the best way to handle translations for stock text in a `SSRS`. For instance - if I have a report that shows a grid of contents what's the best way to have the correct translation for the header of that grid show up, assuming the culture of the report is set correctly.

Put another way - is it possible to do resources in a `SSRS` report, or am I stuck with storing all that text in the database and querying for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AS far as I know, there is no way to localize a report (meaning automating the translation of string litterals)...

Like you said,you basically have to use the User!Language global variable to catch the user's settings and then use that to retrieve the appropriate strings from the DB...

However, you can adapt the display of currency/numeric/date fields according to the user locale. Also possible is changing the interface of the Report Viewer to match your user's langage.

Here are a few links giving tips on how to adapt the locale:

http://www.ssw.com.au/Ssw/Standards/Rules/RulesToBetterSQLReportingServices.aspx#LanguageSetting

Langage pack for Report Viewer:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=e3d3071b-d919-4ff9-9696-c11d312a36a0