# Reporting Services internationalization

Tags: reporting-services, internationalization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Internationalization in SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660/internationalization-in-ssrs)

We use SQL Server Reporting Services for our web reports. At the moment, our clients are all in the UK, so for each report, we set the Language property for the report to "English (United Kingdom)".

But now we have US and French clients. So, we'll need to change the language and currency for the French, and the date format and currency for the Americans. We want to keep one set of reports for all our clients.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Given that the accepted answer is a link to [another SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660/internationalization-in-ssrs) I'd suggest to close this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check out this thread. It might help you here.

[**Internationalization in SSRS**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660/internationalization-in-ssrs)

Answer (score 3):

The report will be rendered with the web browsers language in regard to formatting of dates, currencies and so on if the report's language has not been set. See [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa178910(SQL.80).aspx):

> If the language of the report is not set, the language of the Web browser is used. If the language of the Web browser is not set, the language of the operating system of the report server is used. For example, if you set a specific language on a text box that displays date information, then that text box is always displayed with the date format for that language even if the report, Web browser or server is set to a different language.

Comment: Good point Manga Lee +1! do not apply if you are consuming its web service AFAIK : ) thanks